# Is travel date change possible in between validity of schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, itineraries

I recently got my Schengen visa from Czech Republic Embassy UAE, Validity of visa is from 7 to 30 May with permitted duration of stay is 9 days, my original plan was 7 to 15 may but I want to change date to 10 to 17 may is it possible ?

Comment: As I read it, your new plan is within the limits of the visa you were given, and as such it is possible.

Comment: So as per my understanding with your answer is there won't be any problem if I'll follow new plan which is well inside visa validity dates ?

Answer (score 3):

You have been given extra days of validity for just this purpose. Business meetings may be shifted on short notice, etc.

- You must comply both with duration and validity. Partial days count. 10th to 17th are 8 days, which means you have one day to spare.
- The purpose and itinerary should be recognizably the same. You can change flights and even the airport and country of arrival in the Schengen area, but you should go to the Czech Republic for the purpose you applied for and spend most of the days in the Czech Republic.

Answer (score 1):

Your visa allows you to stay for up to nine days, between 7 and 30 May. Your plan is to stay for eight days from 10 to 17 May. That is up to nine days and between 7 and 30 May. Of course that is valid.